# Switching back and forth between two streams (Observables)

Tags: angular, stream, rxjs, observable

What I'm trying to accomplish is, track the session of the user based on the existence of cookie. I auto logout the user if the session has timed out. To make this happen, I'm waiting for the cookie to appear first, i.e. waiting for the user to make a valid API call. Then, I start querying the cookie until it's not there anymore. The code below works for me the first time. However, after I subscribe to the first stream, I don't have a way to revive it when user starts a new session without reloading the browser.

Code:

```
private _setupSession(): void {

    const waitForCookie = interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          console.log('waiting');
        }),
        switchMap(() => of(this._cookieService.get(COOKIE_STRING))),
        filter((val) => !!val),
        take(1));

    const queryCookie = interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          console.log('querying');
        }),
        switchMap(() => of(this._cookieService.get(COOKIE_STRING))),
        distinct());

    waitForCookie.pipe(concatMap(() => queryCookie))
      .subscribe(
        (val) => {
          if (!val) {
            this._router.navigate([''], {queryParams: {sessionTimedOut: true}});
          }
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
  }
```

Observation:
While user is in login page, I can see '*waiting*' logs every second. Once the user logs in, I start seeing '*querying*' logs every second. Once the session times out, the user is brought back to login page. At this point, I'm still seeing '*querying*' logs in the console. What I'd like to do is switch back to '*waiting*' and switch over to '*querying*' once the user logs in again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement then this is what you want to do:

Watch for the cookie from the `this._cookieService.get()` method and if the value is `null/empty/undefined` then route the user to log in page and keep watching the value of `this._cookieService.get()` on every 1 second.

If my understanding is correct then:

I think you can achieve that by using only one stream like this:

```
const queryCookie = interval(1000)
      .pipe(        
        switchMap(() => of(this._cookieService.get(COOKIE_STRING))),
        //skipwhile will ensure to avoid timeout on starting of the page/app
        skipWhile(cookie => !cookie)
      );

queryCookie
      .subscribe(
        (val) => {
          if (!val) {
            this._router.navigate([''], {queryParams: {sessionTimedOut: true}});
          }
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

BTW - I would suggest not to query on every 1 second. I guess your application might be setting the cookie as null/empty/undefined in the localStorage somehow. If so then you can make your code a bit better by using Subject/BehaviorSubject and you can avoid querying 1 second. This is just an observation as I am not aware of your application design.

Comment: Hi! A single stream would not work for me as there's no cookie to begin with. So, as soon as your stream starts, the user's session will time out since there's no cookie. 1 second is for testing purposes. I'm just playing with idea and trying to see if a feature like this is possible.

Comment: @AnjilDhamala At the start, you can use `startWith("dummyCookie")` operator before `switchMap` so that at the start timeout will not happen.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm having hard time grasping what you're suggesting. I follow that I can startWIth("dummyCookie") but after 1 second interval, when I switch over to getting the actual cookie and the user is still on the first page, the stream will trigger session time out.

Comment: @AnjilDhamala Ah! Try ‘skipWhile(cookie => !cookie)’ operator after switchMap. Remove startWith.

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll get back to you after I implement it.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! Would you mind updating your answer for future visitors?

Comment: @AnjilDhamala Updated the answer to have skipWhile

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the `cookies.onChanged` [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged). You can setup an Observable with [fromEventPattern](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEventPattern), and then perform actions depending on the change. An implementation might look like so:

```
const signedIn$ = fromEventPattern(
 handler => browser.cookies.onChanged.addListener(handler),
 handler => browser.cookies.onChanged.removeListener(handler)
).pipe(
  map(changeInfo => changeInfo.cookie.name === 'myCookie' && changeInfo.removed)
 )
);

signedIn$.subscribe(signedIn => {
  if (signedIn) {...}
  else {...}
})
```

Comment: woah! I didn't know there was something like that. Unfortunately, I need to support IE11 and seems like these events are not supported in Edge, let alone IE.